# Maximum of Subharmonic functions is subharmonic

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have the following definition for subharmonic functions:

$u\in C^0(\bar{\Omega})$ is called subharmonic, if for every ball $B$ with $\bar{B}\in\Omega$ and each function $h\in C^0(\bar{B})$ that is harmonic in $B$ with $u\leq h$ on $\partial B$, we have that $u\leq h$ in $B$.

Using this definition I want to prove the following result:

If $ u_1, u_2$ are subharmonic functions, so is $U=max\left\lbrace u_1, u_2\right\rbrace.$

I have looked for some solutions online, but everywhere I look they use a definition for subharmonic that is built up from the definition of upper semicontinuous functions. I would like help with proving the statement using the definition I have given.

So far I have, take a ball $B$ with $\bar{B}\in \Omega$. If $u_1 \geq u_2$ or $u_2 \geq u_1$ in $B$ we are fine. So suppose that is not the case. It is here that I am unsure how to continue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix any $B$. Suppose $h$ harmonic and $\max(u_1,u_2) \le h$ on $\partial B$. 
Then  $u_1 \le  \max(u_1,u_2) \le h$ on $\partial B$. 
Since $u_1$ subharmonic, $u_1 \le h$ on $B$. Similarly $u_2 \le  \max(u_1,u_2) \le h$ on $\partial B$.  Since $u_2$ subharmonic, $u_2 \le h$ on $B$.

Now $u_1 \le h$ on $B$ and $u_2 \le h$ on $B$ implies $\max(u_1,u_2) \le h$ on $B$ (this can be verified pointwise in $B$). This was for an arbitrary harmonic $h$ which dominated $\max(u_1,u_2)$ on the boundary (of an arbitratry) $B$. Therefore $\max(u_1,u_2)$ is subharmonic .

Comment: I've edited your post. Let me know if I made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Thanks @Quarters! I went through your argument and it seems to work out just fine. I was given a hint to this problem that really made it seem more complicated than it was.